# Flutter Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority

Tags: flutter, androidx, android-fileprovider, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I have an app that is using `flutter_webview_plugin 0.3.8`. I open a webpage in webview and show its content. There is a button in the page and when you press it, it should open a file explorer like it does in normal web browser like chrome.The button works fine in chrome and it opens a bottom widget to choose an action ( camera, files , ...). But in my webview it crashes with the error `Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.booshehr.fileprovider`. The full error is :

```
W/System.err(15213): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.booshehr.fileprovider
W/System.err(15213):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:606)
W/System.err(15213):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
W/System.err(15213):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
W/System.err(15213):    at com.flutter_webview_plugin.WebviewManager.getOutputFilename(WebviewManager.java:272)
W/System.err(15213):    at com.flutter_webview_plugin.WebviewManager.access$800(WebviewManager.java:42)
W/System.err(15213):    at com.flutter_webview_plugin.WebviewManager$3.onShowFileChooser(WebviewManager.java:211)
W/System.err(15213):    at In.a(PG:145)
W/System.err(15213):    at uE0.runFileChooser(PG:2)
W/System.err(15213):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(15213):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
W/System.err(15213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
W/System.err(15213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
W/System.err(15213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(15213):    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
W/System.err(15213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
F/chromium(15213): [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
F/libc    (15213): Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 in tid 15213 (xample.booshehr)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'lge/elsa_global_com/elsa:8.0.0/OPR1.170623.032/18325232422a1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 15213, tid: 15213, name: xample.booshehr  >>> com.example.booshehr <<<
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x714216eb04
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000081  x2   000000007fffffff  x3   0000000000000000
    x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   7f7f7f7f7fffff7f
    x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000001  x11  0000000000000000
    x12  0000007134d6ff00  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  000000716228c000
    x16  000000715dfd2208  x17  000000715df25c50  x18  000000006fba3d30  x19  0000007fd17f5c70
    x20  0000007fd17f5c78  x21  0000007fd17f5c80  x22  000000000000004f  x23  000000715dfd4808
    x24  0000007143e3f000  x25  0000007fd17f5e70  x26  0000000000000001  x27  0000007162612a48
    x28  0000007162612a48  x29  0000007fd17f5c60  x30  000000714216e9c4
    sp   0000007fd17f57b0  pc   000000714216eb04  pstate 0000000060000000
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000001e9fb04  /data/app/com.android.chrome-HU8bsIOJpUMqks882ELhSA==/base.apk (offset 0xc19000)
    #01 pc 0000000001e9f9c0  /data/app/com.android.chrome-HU8bsIOJpUMqks882ELhSA==/base.apk (offset 0xc19000)
```

I have tried adding `provider` to androidmanifest, still the same error:

```xml
<provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                    tools:replace="android:resource" /> 
</provider>
```

my `@xml/filepaths` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<paths> 
<files-path name="myapp" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

Then I tried changing the `android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"` to `android:authorities="${applicationId}.myOwnFileProvider"` , still the same error.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Base from the logs being thrown, it looks like an Android app is being launched using an intent. What's the function on the button displayed inside the WebView? You can use [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) plugin for launching apps on Android via intent i.e.

```dart
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'action_view', // Update with the required action flag
    data: 'package:com.example.booshehr.fileprovider',
  );
  await intent.launch();
}
```

Another possible cause of this issue is that you might be using a plugin that has yet to support the platform that you're running on.